# Kivy update data from other class when click a button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In my App, I have a storage (a Json file), and when I load my app, I have a list that is created from this storage.
I also have a button in this app, and when I click on it, I would like to add something in my storage, and then update my list.
The problem is that the list and the button are 2 separated class, and when I try to call for `list.updateData()`  in my `on_release() # from the button class`, I have to create another instance of my list, and update is not made inside my application.

Here is the code of my entire app :
**planificateur.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
import random
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    name=''
    priority=1
    isActive=True

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        # if is_selected:
        #     print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        # else:
        #     print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))

    def writeInStore(self, name):
        store = JsonStore(name)
        store.put(self.name, priority=self.priority, isActive=self.isActive, task="task")


class RV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.updateData()

    def my_callback(self,dt):
        self.updateData()

    def updateData(self): #I would like to use this method, on the current instance of self when I click on the button. 
        store = JsonStore('test.json')
        self.data = [{'text' : str(task[0]) + " " + str(task[1].get('priority'))} for task in store.find(task="task") ]
        self.refresh_from_data() 

    def addTask(self, task):
        self.taskList.append(task)
        self.updateData()

    def getOneRandom(self):
        pass

class AddTaskButton(ButtonBehavior, Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddTaskButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def collide_point(self, x, y):
        return Vector(x, y).distance(self.center) <= self.width / 2

    def on_release(self):
        task= SelectableLabel();
        task.name ="test22"
        task.priority = 1
        task.isActive = False
        task.writeInStore('test.json')
        rv = RV() #Here I have to call for another instance of RV, so modification are not made inside the running app
        rv.updateData() 
class Main(TabbedPanel):
     pass

class PlanificateurApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PlanificateurApp().run()
```

and **planificateur.kv**

```
<AddTaskButton>:
    size: (min(self.width,self.height),min(self.width,self.height)) # force circle
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.75, 0.75, 0.75
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<SelectableLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: True

<Main>:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        Label:
            text: "app.todayTask"
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab2'
        FloatLayout:
            RV:
                id:rv
            AddTaskButton:
                id:tb
                size_hint: .1, .1
                pos_hint:{'right': 1}
```

`SelectableRecycleBoxLayout` and `SelectableLabel` are from the Kivy tutorial about the Selecatble list of item.
I've put commentary in `RV.updateData()` and in `AddTaskButton.on_release()` to explain.

Do I have to create a singleton from my RV class? (I'm not sure if it's possible in python?) Or do I have a way to retrieve the current instance of RV running in order to call for my function on it?
Or is my logic wrong? I tried to create a function in the `Main` class that retrieve instance of class from id in kv file, but it didn't do anything.
Can Somebody help me?

Comment: Your example is quite complex, please try to provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem. But, the key point is that you must work out what is the relationship between the objects you care about, and use that relationship to get a reference to one object from the other. I wrote some things about this [here](http://inclem.net/2019/06/20/kivy/widget_interactions_between_python_and_kv/).

Comment: How did you try to access the `RV` instance. I think something like `rv = App.get_running_app().root.ids.rv` should work in your `on_release()` method.

Comment: I was trying to create an easier example when you answered @johnAnderson and this is actually a working solution! Thanks for all! 
It doesn't come to my mind that I could actually access my value like this ....